# How can I extract parentheses and the text in between?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract the text between parentheses, with `(` and `)` included, in Python.

I am using the following code:

```py
inspectionsData['test']=inspectionsData['PE DESCRIPTION'].str.extract(r'.*\((.*)\).*')
```

However it returns the text in between only.

This screenshot shows a few examples of the format of the string that I want to extract:

[image: Examples of the String]

Comment: Could you please provide the sample `df` and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Your escaped parenthesis are incorrect. You need to put the grouping parenthesis around the escaped parenthesis `\(` and `\)`. The escaped parenthesis match the actual parenthesis characters in the string.

This should fix it.

```
inspectionsData['test']=inspectionsData['PE DESCRIPTION'].str.extract(r'.*(\(.*\)).*')
```

Comment: Would you please advise how I could remove the same part for the column?
I tried the following but it removes the entire string not the sub.
`inspectionsData['PE DESCRIPTION'].str.extract(r'.*(\(.*\)).*')`

Answer (score 0):

Move the `\(` and `\)` characters that match the parentheses into the capture block:

```
r'.*(\(.*\)).*'
```

Comment: Would you please advise how I could remove the same part for the column? I tried the following but it removes the entire string not the sub. `inspectionsData['PE DESCRIPTION'].str.replace(r'.*(\(.*\)).*,' '')`

Comment: .* at the beginning and end of your regex matches everything until/after the parantheses. You can remove them to match the part inside parentheses only.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply with the built-in `re` (regex) library:

```py
import re

def main():
    txt = "FOOD MKT RETAIL (1-1,999 SF) HIGH RISK"
    pattern = "\(.*\)"

    matched = re.findall(pattern, txt)
    first_match = matched[0]

    print("first_match: ", first_match)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```sh
first_match:  (1-1,999 SF)
```